Model still overfits after hyperparameter tuning, dataset balancing and convolution layering
I am trying to classify either an image of 25x25 px stacked together as 50x25 px is the same(1) or different(0). I am using keras to create the NN layers. There are 10,000 instances of both 1s and 0s in the training set while there are 2000 images of 1s and 500 images of 0s in the validation set.
Sample Dataset of same(1):

Sample Dataset of different(0):

The Keras sequential layers are shown below:
layers.Input((2*imsize,imsize,3)),            
layers.Reshape((2,imsize,imsize,3)),          
layers.LayerNormalization(axis=[-1,-2,-3]),   
layers.Flatten(),                             
layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'),           
layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')    

Then I compiled the layers using adam optimiser with loss and accuracy like so:
ml.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
       loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False), 
       metrics=['accuracy'])
ml_hist = ml.fit(x=training_dataset, epochs=20, validation_data = validation_dataset, shuffle=True)

After that, I trained the model using epoch=20 and batch_size=100. I got these as a result after plotting it based on epoch.
Results

After trying to balance the validation set to 500 1s and 500 0s, the result still overfits

I've even removed regularisation and added 2 Convolution and pooling layer to no avail. It just result in lower accuracy
layers.Input((2*imsize,imsize,3)),               
layers.Reshape((2*imsize,imsize,3)),          
layers.LayerNormalization(axis=[-1,-2,-3]),  

# New Layers 
layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

layers.Flatten(),                             
layers.Dropout(rate=0.7),                            
layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'),           
layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')   


My question is: How do I fix this overfitting issue? I dont know what Im doing wrong, I have tried changing the learning rate to 0.1, 0.01 and 0.001. I've also tried adding a Dropout layer of 0.2, 0.5 and 0.7 after Flatten() before ReLu.

A bit late, hope you solved it! Do not add Dropout just after flatten layer and before the dense layer because your are loosing 70% of information, the correct sequence is
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'),
layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')
